# Venmo me button duplicate

Tags: html, button, duplicates, duplication, venmo

I've embedded the new Venmo Me button into my website, but for some reason the button shows up with many duplicates. It seems the duplication error occurs based on the number of dividers (div, section, p, etc.) - I get an extra button for each one I put in. I'm thinking it might be the code that comes with the Venmo Me button, but is there anything I can change in my code to fix this?

Comment: share your code here..

Comment: I'd suggest [contacting Venmo directly](https://help.venmo.com/customer/portal/emails/new).